# NPM Sinon requires buster-xxx?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm using [mochify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mochify) for unit testing, and would like to add some spies/mocks/stub capabilities. The package to use, it seems, is [sinon](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sinon), but my experience has been:

1) Install sinon as described in the docs and a dozen or more tutorials:

```
npm install sinon --save-dev
```

2) Add a spy to my tests:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');

...

it('yadda yadda', function() {
    var callback = sinon.spy();

    ...
```

3) Run my tests:

```
mochify
```

But what I get is:

```
Error: module "buster-core" not found from ...
```

What is buster? If I npm install buster-core, I just get another one; buster-test. I install that one and need buster-assertions...

What's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was mochify was trying to test Sinon itself... bad config on my part.

I fixed it by focusing mochify's testing to only my app directory as it should have been. Also I forked SinonJS (https://github.com/nicholasstephan/Sinon.JS.git) and added the `/test` directory the it's `.npmignore` as seems to be good practice. ([Exclude test code in npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617753/exclude-test-code-in-npm-package))