# How to test an `npm publish` result, without actually publishing to NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

One common problem I have, is that sometimes my .npmignore file is too aggressive, and I ignore files that I actually will to include in the NPM tarball.

My question is - is there a way to test the results of NPM publish, without actually publishing to NPM?

I am thinking something like this. Assuming I have a local NPM package with package name "foo"

```
set -e;
local proj="bar";
local path_to_foo="."
mkdir -p "$HOME/.local.npm"
npm --tarball -o "$HOME/.local.npm"  # made up command, but you get the idea
(
  cd "$HOME/.temp_projects"
  rm -rf "$proj"
  mkdir "$proj"
  cd "$proj"
  npm init -f
  npm install "$path_to_foo"
)
copy_test_stuff -o "$HOME/.temp_projects/bar"

cd "$HOME/.temp_projects/bar"
npm test
```

I don't think this will work. Because whatever we include in the NPM publish tarball, might not have enough to do the full test. But maybe if we copy all the test files (including fixtures, etc) when we do `copy_test_stuff`, it might work?

Comment: this is from 2012, but has some info: http://podefr.tumblr.com/post/30488475488/locally-test-your-npm-modules-without-publishing

Comment: Rather than do a single npm pack, I'd do what Facebook does on create-react-app https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3744 .They mock a registry as verdaccio, publish and test against other dependencies. It's a reliable way because you test the whole workflow without a lot of hassle. Babel.js, pnpm and mozilla neutrino does the same. I think is a smart way to handle this.

Comment: @JuanPicado cool, if you can add that as an answer instead of a comment, probably get some upvotes

Answer (score 98):

Simply run:

```
npm publish --dry-run
```

or, with tarball generation in the current directory

```
npm pack
```

In `npm 6` and up, these will display what files are going to be uploaded.

#### docs

- [`npm publish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/commands/npm-publish#dry-run)
- [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/commands/npm-pack) *(now it also supports `--dry-run`)*

Answer (score 20):

I'll elaborate my comment I posted earler, (thanks Alexander Mills).

I'm a `verdaccio` contributor, so, I closely follow whom are implementing and how to verdaccio. I'll describe couples or examples (e2e mostly) that I've found and might be interesting or as a valid answer.

#### create-react-app

By far, the most popular integration. Let me give you some context, they are using `lerna` and have multiple packages that need to test before to publish on main registry aka (`npmjs`). I'll [quote here Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/951427300070916096) explaining their reasons to use a custon registry.

The [script is self-explanatory](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3744/files) but let me highlight some parts.

```
+nohup npx verdaccio@2.7.2 &>$tmp_registry_log &
+# Wait for `verdaccio` to boot
+grep -q 'http address' <(tail -f $tmp_registry_log)
+
+# Set registry to local registry
+npm set registry http://localhost:4873
+yarn config set registry http://localhost:4873
+
+# Login so we can publish packages
+npx npm-cli-login@0.0.10 -u user -p password -e user@example.com -r http://localhost:4873 --quotes

 # Test local start command
 yarn start --smoke-test

+./tasks/release.sh --yes --force-publish=* --skip-git --cd-version=prerelease --exact --npm-tag=latest
```

As you see, they are running `verdaccio` and instead a custom config file they have decided to use `npm-cli-login` and then they run the tests against verdaccio. When all is ready, they publish on verdaccio. As last step, later in the same file, they fetch packages with their own app.

#### pnpm

They have created a project called [pnpm-registry-mock](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm-registry-mock) which is an abstraction that allows them to run verdaccio before running the tests.

```
 "pretest:e2e": "rimraf ../.tmp/ && rimraf node_modules/.bin/pnpm && pnpm-registry-mock prepare",
 "test:e2e": "preview --skip-prepublishOnly && npm-run-all -p -r pnpm-registry-mock test:tap",
 "test": "npm run lint && npm run tsc && npm run test:e2e",
```

Basically, using npm scripts they prepare verdaccio and run the test as last step. I cannot go too much into details, since I've only saw it shallowly. But I know what it does.

#### Mozilla Neutrino

This is [work in progress](https://github.com/mozilla-neutrino/neutrino-dev/pull/778), but, it's also interesting to mention here.

```
+if [ "$PROJECT" == "all" ]; then
+  yarn link:all;
+  yarn validate:eslintrc;
+  yarn lint;
+  yarn build;
+  yarn test;
+else
+  yarn verdaccio --config verdaccio.yml & sleep 10;
+  yarn config set registry "http://localhost:4873";
+  npm config set registry "http://localhost:4873";
+  .scripts/npm-adduser.js;
+  yarn lerna publish \
+    --force-publish=* \
+    --skip-git \
+    --skip-npm \
+    --registry http://localhost:4873/ \
+    --yes \
+    --repo-version $(node_modules/.bin/semver -i patch $(npm view neutrino version));
+  yarn lerna exec npm publish --registry http://localhost:4873/;
+  PROJECT="$PROJECT" TEST_RUNNER="$TEST_RUNNER" LINTER="$LINTER" yarn test:create-project;
+fi
```

Again, the same approach, project is being built and then `verdaccio` is being executed and they publish all packages.

#### Babel.js

I know Babel.js has been experimenting with a smoke-testing for Babel 6 and have [plans to integrate a registry with Babel 7](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6134). I [quote **Henry Zhu** early this year talking about `babel-smoke-tests`](https://twitter.com/left_pad/status/951455336464113664) in the same thread of `create-react-app`.

The experiment is called [babel-smoke-tests](https://github.com/motiz88/babel-smoke-tests) and  `babel-smoke-tests/scripts/test.sh` is the key file for you.

Here I see the same pattern than other projects. They are launching `verdaccio` and then they do their stuff.

```
START=$(cd scripts; pwd)/section-start.sh
END=$(cd scripts; pwd)/section-end.sh

$START 'Setting up local npm registry' setup.npm.registry
node_modules/.bin/verdaccio -l localhost:4873 -c verdaccio.yml &

export NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=http://localhost:4873/

NPM_LOGIN=$(pwd)/scripts/npm-login.sh

$NPM_LOGIN

$END 'Done setting up local npm registry' setup.npm.registry

scripts/bootstrap.sh

export THEM=$(cd them; pwd)

if [[ $SPECIFIC_TEST ]]; then
    scripts/tests/$SPECIFIC_TEST.sh
else
    scripts/tests/jquery.sh
    scripts/tests/react.sh
fi
```

### Wrap up

First of all, I hope my small research give you new ideas how to address your issue. I think `npm pack` solve some issues, but **mocking a registry using `verdaccio` which is quite light and straightforward to use might be a real option for you**. Some big projects are being (or getting started) using it and they follow more or less the same approach. So, Why don't try? :)

https://www.verdaccio.org/

Comment: sure verdaccio sounds cool, although I think `npm pack` should suffice, mocking a registry might be harder, error prone, etc.

Comment: `npm pack` does effectively probe the content of the tarball, but you lose the ability to prove whether resolve dependencies and transitive dependencies works fine. Here a presentation I did for such purpose (related with my answer) https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1L5wD3BiywXmNASz9yy7ps4EvKLp9BodVgn0d_JO9kVo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: With verdaccio and [npmrc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmrc), you can publish a bunch of interdependent packages (to localhost) and use `npm install` to make sure their deps work.

verdaccio has a lot of deps so I installed `npmrc` globally, `mkdir ~/.npmrcs/verdaccio-server && (cd $_ && npm init -y && npm install --save verdaccio)` to have a server that I can start whenever I change to the testing profile (`npmrc test`); easy to find but mildly messy 'cause npmrc lists verdaccio-server as an npm profile.

`rm -r .local/share/verdaccio/storage/<your packages>` to clean after testing.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem, so I created a package called [package-preview](https://github.com/zkochan/package-preview). What package-preview does is:

1. packs your package (it is what npm does before publish)
2. installs your package in a temp location
3. links the package to your project's node_modules

This allows you to basically require the package as a dependency in your tests. So in tests of "awesome-pkg", intead of `require('../lib')` you write `require('awesome-pkg')`

I use this package in all the pnpm repos for several months and it works really well. I also posted an article about this package that explains all the different errors that it can catch: [Never ever forget to install a dependency](https://medium.com/pnpm/never-ever-forget-to-install-a-dependency-1c39dd3bbb37)

Comment: nice that's basically what I did with `r2g`, except I don't link the node_modules folder. part of the purpose is to test the postinstall/preinstall routine, so you are cheating your people! :) I expect whatever package I am testing to export a function called r2gSmokeTest from `main`, this function smoke tests their package, they have to implement it.

Comment: after reading this again, this is a really good solution. however the main tests have to be written where it `require('x')` instead of `require('../../x')`

Comment: That is what `pnpm link -g` allows you to do, FYI

Answer (score 5):

Referring to npm docs:

> [--dry-run] As of npm@6, does everything publish would do except
> actually publishing to the registry. Reports the details of what would
> have been published.

> Similar to --dry-run see npm pack, which figures out the files to be included and packs them into a tarball to be uploaded to the registry.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-publish#description

Comment: i never understood why to give a _nearly verbatim copy_ of an answer 1-2-3 years after someone published a good answer (and it was accepted). https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584801/1115187 already contains `npm publish --dry run`

Comment: @maxkoryukov that answer lacked information before edit also was not selected for answer

Comment: whoops, I didn't read the history of changes in that answer. My apologies

Answer (score 3):

I see too many complicated answers, but according to documentation, you just need to install your local package globally (because it will be installed on different directory)

Go to your module root directory and do

```
npm install . -g
```

Comment: This works okay but doesn't take into account the whitelisting implemented by using the `files` keyword in `package.json`